# Texture Memory Usage

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to find out how much texture memory does consumed from my application. There are following types of texture and calculations by me:

1. RGB textures -> textureWidth * textureHeight * 3 (memory usage)
2. RGBA textures -> textureWidth * textureHeight * 4 (memory usage)

As a result I am wondering that can graphics driver allocate much more memory than above calculated memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few simple answers:

To the best of my knowledge, it's been around 2 decades since (the majority of) hardware devices supported *packed* 24bit RGB data. In modern hardware this is usually represented in an "XRGB" (or equivalent) format where there is one padding byte per pixel. It is painful in hardware to efficiently handle pixels that straddle cache lines etc.   Further, since many applications (read "games") use [texture compression](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/a/1551/209), having support for fully packed 24bit seems a bit redundant.

Texture dimensions: If a texture's dimensions are not 'nice' for the *particular* hardware (e.g,. maybe, say, x is not a multiple of 16bytes, or, say, 4x4 or 8x8 blocks), then the driver may pad the physical size of the texture.

Finally, if you have MIP mapping (and you do want [this for performance](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/a/419/209) as well as quality reasons), it will expand the texture size by around 33%.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I am thinking that padding may occur so I will look for details.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer from Simon F, it's also worth noting that badly written applications can force the driver to allocate memory for multiple copies of the same texture. This can occur if it attempts to modify the texture while it is still referenced by an in-flight rendering operation. This is commonly known as "resource copy-on-write" or "resource ghosting".

Blog here explains in more detail:

https://community.arm.com/developer/tools-software/graphics/b/blog/posts/mali-performance-6-efficiently-updating-dynamic-resources